# Is it possible to choose which dictionary keys I want to print in Python?

Tags: python, dictionary, key

This is my first post so please bear with me. I'm currently in an introductory computer science class and our final project is to make a text based game where you move room to room and collect objects. I want to provide the player with their possible moves so they're not wasting their time running into walls. The code I have works as long as the player chooses to pick up the object in the room. However, if they leave the object then 'item' is printed in the possible moves since it was not appended. These are my thoughts but I'm struggling to fully connect the dots in my head:

```
if 'item' in rooms[current_room]:
    print(rooms[current_room].keys())  <---- would I add some kind of range here [:]? I'm not sure how I would do that.
```

Maybe a 'for' loop would work? Something like

```
for keys in range.....
```

I don't want to remove the key, I just don't want it to print. Any advice will be appreciated! Here's the code that is giving me trouble:

```
rooms = {

    'Living Room': {'North': 'Master Bedroom', 'South': 'Kitchen', 'East': 'Laundry Room', 'West': 'Front Porch'},
    'Laundry Room': {'North': 'Back Door', 'West': 'Living Room', 'item': 'Fancy Duds'},
    'Back Door': {'South': 'Laundry Room', 'item': 'Nice Shoes'},
    'Kitchen': {'North': 'Living Room', 'East': 'Your Room', 'item': 'Half-Eaten Box of Chocolates'},
    'Your Room': {'West': 'Kitchen', 'item': 'Cheap Cologne'},
    'Front Porch': {'East': 'Living Room', 'item': 'Freshly Picked Flowers'},
    'Master Bedroom': {'South': 'Living Room', 'East': 'Master Bathroom', 'item': 'Flashlight'},
    'Master Bathroom': {'West': 'Master Bedroom', 'item': 'YOUR MOTHER'}  # villian
}

current_room = 'Laundry Room'

possible_moves = rooms[current_room].keys()

print('Possible Moves:', *possible_moves)
```

Comment: what did you try to do? You said `Maybe a 'for' loop` but you didn't try it. FIrst you could try to use `for`-loop

Comment: I was starting to work on a for loop when I posted this. I honestly wasn't sure how fast I would get a response to my question so I posted before I really worked on my loop. Now I know there are some fast responders on here. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You could filter the bothering key ('item') this way:

```py
possible_moves = [move for move in rooms[current_room].keys() if move != "item"]
print('Possible Moves:', possible_moves)
```

This is equivalent to your idea of using a for loop for it, like this:

```py
possible_moves = []
for move in rooms[current_room].keys():
    if move != 'item':
         possible_moves.append(move)
print(possible_moves)
```

Comment: Thank you! This is where my brain was trying to go but my Python knowledge base is still pretty small so I wasn't sure how to get there. Thank you for writing it both ways as well, it helps me understand the process.